# Tag score doesn't seem to have updated for a few days

Tags: bug, tag-score

I'm getting pretty close to a silver badge in a tag that I'm very interested in so over the past couple of days I have looked at my own profile daily just to see how close I am. That is when I noticed that even when I got up votes for answers with that tag, the tag score didn't update.

I found a post on meta that said that the tag-score script runs daily at 03:00 so I figured that it would soon be updated. However I haven't yet seen an update.

This is what I see in my profile

[image]

and this is what I see when fetch all my up voted answers by tag.

[image]

The tag I've been following closely is the "core animation" tag. So I can looking at the last 6 up voted answers for that tag to get an estimate of when the script last ran. This is my reputation history for the past few days with the questions with this tag highlighted:

[image]

## It seems like tag score was last updated March 8 (5 days ago)